# Solutions to an Equation

Tags: functions

I was wondering how to find the real solutions to this equation algebraically:
$$0=\left(\sin\pi x\right)^2+\sin\left(\frac{n}{x}\pi\right)^2$$ if $n$ is known.

Comment: You should note that you have two non-negative quantities being equal to zero, that means that they both must be zero, the roots of $\sin x$ are $0+2k\pi$ or $\pi +2k\pi$ with $k$ being just an integer (the $2k\pi$ is there just because $\sin$ is periodic with period $2\pi$)... That being said, given a $n$ your solutions would be all the $x$ that divide $n$, or in a more "compact" way, the equation holds $\forall x$ s.t. $x|n$

Comment: Yes, I realized that but how do I solve for $x$?

Comment: It's very simple, a way would be to factor $n$ in it's prime power decomposition, then with that you can check all the divisors of $n$, let me do an example to clear things out, consider $n=6$, it's prime power decomposition is: $6=2 \cdot 3$ that means that it's divisors are $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3$ and $\pm 6$, therefore your solutions are: $x=\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3,  \pm 6$

Comment: The point of the equation is that I don't have to factor $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write: $$(sin πx)^2>=0$$ and  $$(sin \frac{n}{x}π)^2>=0$$
and when you add them up, you have:
          $$(sin πx)^2 + (sin \frac{n}{x}π)^2>=0$$

In the case of solving your equation, equality in the third inequality takes place - which means that equality takes place in the first two inequalities too (suppose this were not true, one of the squares would be greater than 0, which would mean that $(sin πx)^2 +  (sin \frac{n}{x}π)^2>0$, contradicting the equation to solve)

Therefore, you have $(sin πx)=0$ and  $(sin \frac{n}{x}π)=0$

$(sin πx)=0$ is equivalent to $πx=πk,  k  ∈ \mathbb{Z}  $  , which means $x ∈ \mathbb{Z}$
$(sin \frac{n}{x}π)=0$ is equivalent to $\frac{n}{x}π = πk,  k  ∈ \mathbb{Z}   $, which means: $x=n/k,  k  ∈ \mathbb{Z}   $

Therefore, x is a whole number which satisfies $x=n/k$, where   $n  ∈ \mathbb{N}   $ (I assume from the notation) and $ k  ∈ \mathbb{Z}   $, which means *x is a divisor of n*.

So, if we let $S $= set of solutions of given equation, $S\subseteq D_n$, the set of the (both positive and negative) divisors of n.

We can check that indeed every divisor of n verifies the given equation, therefore $D_n \subseteq S$, which, along with earlier-proved $S\subseteq D_n$, gives us $S = D_n$

The set of solutions for this equation is the set of both negative and positive divisors of n.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but how do I solve for $x$ by transforming the whole formula, not just parts.

Comment: You could denote $a=sin (πx)$ and $b= sin (\frac{n}{x}pi)$, which would reduce your equation to $a^2+b^2=0$, equivalent to $(a+b)^2-2ab=0$. Using from here $$sin(m)+sin(n)=2sin(\frac{m+n}{2})cos(\frac{m-n}{2})$$ and $$sin(m)*sin(n)=\frac{cos(m-n)-cos(m+n)}{2}$$ might help.

Comment: Hmmm, I am confused. How does this help?

Comment: Because after that I get this: $$\cos\left(2\pi x\right)+\cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}{x}\right)-2$$ which doesn't help much.

Comment: Factorize $cos(2πx)+cos(\frac{2nπ}{x})$ as $2cos(\frac{2πx+\frac{2nπ}{x}}{2}) cos(\frac{2πx-\frac{2nπ}{x}}{2})$ which is clearly, less (or equal) than 2, with equality when both terms are either -1 or 1. Yet I believe this still isn't 'algebraic' enough, isn't it?

Comment: No I guess not. Is there any way to combine the two cosines?

Comment: Because after I divided out the $2$ out of $$2cos(\frac{2πx+\frac{2nπ}{x}}{2}) cos(\frac{2πx-\frac{2nπ}{x}}{2})$$ I got $$\cos\left(\frac{\left(2\pi x+\frac{2n\pi}{x}\right)}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\left(2\pi x-\frac{2n\pi}{x}\right)}{2}\right)-1$$

Comment: Which then simplified to $$\left(\cos\left(\frac{\left(\pi x^2+n\pi\right)}{x}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\left(\pi x^2-n\pi\right)}{x}\right)\right)-1$$

Comment: Could I combine the cosines now?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the left side, $(sin(x\pi))^2=0 $ if and only if x is an integer.

Same goes for the right side, so $\frac{n}{x}$ must be an integer.
for every i that satisfy $i|n$ both of them will work. so for every $x$ that $x|n$ the equation is true

Comment: But how can i get the zeroes algebraically.

Comment: What do you mean by "algebrically" ?

Comment: I mean can you solve for x by transforming the equation.

Comment: You can take the devirative. 0 is to lowest point of the function so you can look where the devirative is zero and this lead you to the minimum points, this is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, but how do you find the derivative.

Comment: https://www.derivative-calculator.net/ you can see step by step.. but like every function, n is just a number

Comment: So how do I use this to find the minima?

Comment: Hey, I don't know if you'll respond but I did try to simplify the equation and got this: $$\cos\left(\frac{\left(\pi x^2+n\pi\right)}{x}\right)-\sec\left(\frac{\left(\pi x^2-n\pi\right)}{x}\right)=0$$ Is it possible to solve for $x$ now?

Comment: Idk.. sorry bro